# jQuery append new li element with classes?

Tags: jquery, append

I am trying to add functionality onto this [todo list](http://www.cssflow.com/snippets/simple-to-do-list/demo) by Thibaut Courouble, and so far all seems easy until I press the '+' symbol. I have asked a simple prompt and got the text and used jQuery append() to add new element to the list. However, when I click on the checkbox, it ignores the jQuery's .click that targets that element.

So far I am currently using jQuery's on() method, however this doesn't seem to work.

Basically the JavaScript is asking for text, then appending a new li in the main ul.

HTML

```
<ul class="todo-list">
 <li class="done"><a href="#" class="toggle">Toggle</a> Find an idea.</li>
 <li><a href="#" class="toggle">Toggle</a> Build it!</li>
 <li><a href="#" class="toggle">Toggle</a> Ship it...<br>with a line break!</li>
</ul>
```

Javascript

```
$(".icon-delete").click(function() {
  if ($(".todo-list > li").hasClass("done")) {
    $("li.done").remove();
  }
});

$(".toggle").click(function() {
  $(this).parent().toggleClass("done");
});

$(".icon-add").on("click", function() {
  var text = window.prompt("Enter text");
  $(".todo-list").append('<li><a href=\"#\" class=\"toggle\">Toggle</a> '+text+'</li>');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mmTRS/

Comment: please provide some code, what have you done so far?

Comment: Got it. Had some jsFiddle trouble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the `toggle` elements are added dynamically, you need to add delegated event registration model like

```
$(document).on('click',".toggle",function() {
    $(this).parent().toggleClass("done");
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/hGsBm/)

Comment: I tried the .toggle(), didn't seem to work at first. It does now! Thanks for finding the solution!